# How do I refresh the hosts file on OS X?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to develop using subdomains on OSX but don't want to reboot the computer to refresh the hosts file. Normally on linux I'd do `/etc/init.d/networking restart` but I can't figure out how to do this on OSX.

Comment: You probably just need to clear your web browser's cache.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You don't need to. Simply `sudo vim /etc/hosts`, change what you need to change and go on. Your changes will be applied instantly.

If `ping yourdomain.com` still gives you the wrong IP, try clearing your DNS cache:

OSX 10.4 and below: `lookupd -flushcache`
OSX 10.5 + 10.6: `dscacheutil -flushcache`
OSX 10.7 + 10.8: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
OSX 10.9 and above: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
OSX 10.12 and above: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`
OSX 10.14.5 and above: `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: For clearing dns cache, see: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227988627-How-to-clear-the-DNS-Cache-

Comment: Make sure you obviously use the right order too (IP address, then DNS).

Comment: @user1442960 That sounds so simple, but I had a brain fart and added host entries that were incorrect. As vzwick said, the changes were applied instantly as soon as I corrected them.

Comment: OSX 10.12 here, `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` was just enough to clear the cache

Comment: On MacOS 10.14.5 `dscacheutil -flushcache` was enough

Comment: Ventura 13.5 this no longer works, or at least not for ssh

Answer (score 10):

For macOS El Capitan (10.11), go to the Terminal app and type:

> sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

[Source](https://supra888.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/refresh-the-hosts-file-in-osx-el-capitan/)

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Sierra (10.12):

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

from
https://www.indabaa.com/how-to-reset-flush-dns-cache-in-macos-sierra/

Answer (score 0):

I understand from https://serverfault.com/questions/478534/how-is-dns-lookup-configured-for-osx-mountain-lion that /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf are really no longer used on OS X Sierra 10.12.* (and probably earlier). Indeed when I tried to add hosts to /etc/hosts and reset the cache with the above instructions, the hosts were not recognized, via the host command. However, ping does recognize them.

The networksetup command replaces the "old" way of doing things, or use the Network GUI. For example, to specify dns servers to use:

```
sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to enter a command to open the Nano text editor. You will need your administrator password, as well. type sudo nano /etc/hosts and then hit return. Enter your administrator password and then hit return.