# How do I do this on a mac instead of windows?

Tags: windows, mac, steam

I want to do this (see video) quite badly, but the problem is I have a Mac and not a windows. So I get lost after system32 and what not. Please help! :c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UucAscSUEvs

Comment: In the future, please describe your problem with words, if possible. A video is fine as supplementary information, but not like this.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/346518/how-do-i-refresh-the-hosts-file-on-os-x/346519#346519

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac the hosts file can be found at /etc/hosts, and the SteamApps files are in /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps (replace username with your Mac username).

You may need administrator privileges to edit the files. If so, open Terminal and type, for example, `sudo nano "/etc/hosts"`.

Of course, as the video is demonstrating a bug on Windows, that big won't necessarily exist on a Mac - let us know if it still works!

Comment: My apologies to everyone. I meant to use this link instead https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhaUC9fA7z0

Comment: I can't see any difference in the instructions in those two videos - the same answers still apply.

Answer (score -1):

The hosts file is located at `/etc/hosts` on regular UNIX and Linux systems.